# Default "Viewing" Cell Background options for Excel 365

Tags: excel, colors, background, cell, default

I hope I can convey this question the right way. First of all, I do not mean change the background color of cells to a different color manually. What I mean is the default color of the cells where the user has not specified a color. Please read the below.

In previous versions of Excel, I remember being able to setup a *default viewing color* to gray. What I mean by *viewing color* is, if I opened a new workbook, background color of all the cells by default *would look gray* in my computer. If I added data to this spreadsheet leaving all the background cells to defaults and emailed the file to someone, that person would see the background for all cells as white (their default viewing background cell color). If this other person made changes and highlighted a cell range yellow, saved and sent the file back, I would see the highlighted range as yellow, but would still see the other cells as gray.

How do you accomplish this Excel 365? I cannot a way to accomplish this functionality anywhere in Excel 365. What I found online is only ways to change background colors that are local to the spreadsheet I am working on, not Excel as a whole. Word and Outlook allow me to work on documents showing a black background with white letters, but that is not the way other computers will see my documents/emails. How do I setup Excel 365 to have that viewing functionality as well? Can you please advise? Thanks.